# How can i load external domain page inside a div with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to load the external domain say http://www.google.com inside div without using iframe with JQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use load function $( "div" ).load('http://google.com');

But it will work only with CORS disabled.

Comment: is any way to disabled the cors by jquery ?

Comment: @dgk no, you can only disable it in browser, for chrome you should use --disable-web-security key.

Answer (score 2):

use a iframe

`<div>
    <iframe id='myIFrame' src='http://www.google.com'></iframe>
</div>`

from js you can change the src as shown below

$("#myIFrame").attr('src', your_Url_Here)